# Issue in Jquery mobile Footer

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

When I use hyperlinks in the footer, it looks like a button, but when I run it I want it to look like a simple html link? What could be the simple solution for that?

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" style="text-align: center">
    <a href="index.html">about</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="index.html">T&C</a><span>|</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery auto-enhances links. A simple way around it is to add a `data-role="none"` to the anchor tags, i.e.:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" style="text-align: center">
        <a href="index.html" data-role="none">about</a><span>|</span>
        <a href="index.html" data-role="none">T&C</a><span>|</span>
</div>
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3GMCe/) for a demo.